# Getting elevation point from DTED file using ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF?

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, dted

I am still new to the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF.

My project requires me to get the elevation point offline (local) from a DTED file. I had raster map view using mapview, then I want to get the elevation point when I point the mouse tip on raster map that I view.

This is my code so far:

```
string parentFolder = @"C:\Data\DTED0";
List<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(parentFolder, "*.dt0", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

Scene.BaseSurface = new Surface();
RasterElevationSource rasterElevationSource = new RasterElevationSource(files);

Scene.BaseSurface.ElevationSources.Add(rasterElevationSource);
```

Do I need to create new user control for sceneview or just use the that i read raster map on mapview?

Answer (score 2):

Clicking with the Identify tool (Tools toolbar) on an elevation raster should return the elevation value at that point. I have only used DTEDs as output, but I believe they work the same as DEMs/elevation rasters. Since DTEDs come in different resolutions, you could get an interpolated elevation for a small area, rather than a 1-meter or submeter value that you could get from an elevation raster.

If you have access to the Spatial Analyst extension, there is a tool called [Extract Values to Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm) that can assign raster values to a point file, which is useful when you have a lot of points to assign elevations to.

Comment: On ArcGIS it need to use other platform to get the elevation point from Dted file? Before this I retrieve the elevation point using the interpolation method on GDAL just by add the library and few code. I though i can the same method on the ArcGIS SDK.